# How do you prototype a function with an enable_if<>::type return type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

Below I have 3 prototypes. I expected the first one (commented out) to work, but that's the only one that *doesn't* work (see comments in code for errors). Even more surprising to me is that either of the following 2 work, even when both are present.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Prototypes:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Causes "ambiguous call to overloaded function" at the call site when when one or both  
//  of the below prototypes is also present. Otherwise causes unresolves external
//template<typename T> void func(); 

//  Okay, can have this one AND/OR the below declaration
template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type func();

//  Also okay, can have this one AND/OR the above declaration
template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type func();


int main()
{
    func<int>();
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Definitions:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type func() {}

template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type func() {}
```

Which is the correct prototype, and why doesn't the first one work? I'm using VS2010 & VS2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one causes the error because it declares a different function template. To put it simply, it is different because all the `enable_if` thingies are part of its signature, not just the final type it resolves to.

You never provide a definition for that first template declaration, and that's why you get an "unresolved external" error if you don't put the others in.

If you put the others in, now you have one of the others *plus* this one as a candidate, and both are viable, and not ordered. That's why you get an "ambiguous call" error.

The correct way is to declare the ones you define, i.e., exactly what you have uncommented right now.

Comment: Woah. `enable_if` is part of it's signature? That's... strange. I was hoping the signature would be whatever the `enable_if` stuff resolves to in the end.

Comment: @Dave I think the problem is that `enable_if` is only resolved on instantiation, and the compiler needs to know if they're different or not as soon as she sees the declarations. And yes, it has annoyed me too in the past :(

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The comment is completely wrong. The two declarations can coexist as long as you don't try to call it with a type for which both templates are valid. It can see and process both declarations, as it can be trivially demonstrated by removing the instantiation from the program in the question.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez yes, but she always considers them different. She never considers them the same, which would require some substitution to happen without instantiation. Sorry if that wasn't clear above.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: There cannot be partial specializations for function templates, and that means that either they are the exactly the same or they are different. Also regarding the more specialized, the one with `enable_if` would be more specialized *if* the return type was used at all in overload resolution, but that not being the case the possible order does not matter at all.